# configure web.config to point to a rootfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-express, virtual-directory

Could you please help me configure web.config, so that IIS express resolves all URLs, beginning form my physical root folder.

For example I want all my web files in Visual Studio to have "webroot" folder:

```
C:/dev/myWebMvcApplication/webroot/app/index.html
```

Where: `myWebMvcApplication` is the folder for my solution, [.sln]
and `webroot` is a physical folder containing all my files; so that, all URLs could look like

```
/localhost:port/app/index.html
```

and not like

```
/localhost:port/webroot/app/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of IIS7 changing sites within your server is generally done now in the sites section of applicationHost.config.

```
<sites>
    <site name="Blah Blah" id="1">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:/dev/myWebMvcApplication/webroot" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="HTTP" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
        </bindings>
     </site>
</sites>
```

I am assuming you are are talking about changing the root of your webserver so that all applications under your solution share the same base URL. Please let me know if this is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way? - that is more source control friendly (portable) ? (so no through applicationHost.config, but through, web.config) ?

Comment: Unfortunately I know of no way to set a root virtual directory location in your web.config. It's really intended to be done within the IISAdmin management extension. If you're looking to do some form of build/deploy automation a PowerShell script would likely work but that's really a totally different thing.